# Excel Alternate Row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, openxml-sdk, conditional-formatting

I have created a conditional format rule for alternate row style. It changes the cell fill for the cell to some color. The problem i have with this is that It override any other formatting that is already on the cell. So if the cell already has a background fill it will override it. I don't want this to happen.[image]

How can i write another formula or change this formula so it does not do a fill when the cell already has fill.

Formula: `=MOD(ROW()/2,1)>0`

Answer (score 1):

Define the following UDF to return the color of a cell

```
Public Function InteriorColor(Arange As Range)
InteriorColor = Arange.Interior.ColorIndex
End Function
```

Now change your conditional formatting, starting at C6 and copying down

```
=AND(InteriorColor(C6)=-4142,MOD(ROW()/2,1)>0)
```

ColorIndex -4142 is no fill (xlColorIndexNone) , so this only applies formatting if there is no existing fill.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @user2465348, saves me a lot of time. I am using openXML to do all of these in c#. Hopefully i get it working. Thank you once again.